# I am confused about the correct use of "what" in this sentence

Tags: pronouns, relative-clauses, clauses, determiners, exclamatives

Is the sentence below a correct sentence? If so, what kind of a sentence is this, and what is the role of the word "what" in this sentence? Is this sentence supposed to be an exclamatory sentence?

> She doesn't know what a great teacher he is.

Answer (score 1):

> *She doesn't know* [*what a great teacher he is*].

Yes, it's okay. The bracketed element is an exclamative clause in which "what" is an adjective functioning as an external modifier in the noun phrase "what a great teacher".

The initial exclamative phrase can be linked with a gap in the exclamative clause:

"what a great teacher *i* he is ___*i*"

The exclamative clause is functioning as complement of the  verb "know".

Comment: Thank you so much for this clarification. I am very grateful.